# Shiny nearPoints() with slider input

Tags: r, shiny, slider, interactive

I was wondering if I can get rows data using `nearPoints()` from an interactive graph with slider input. My app.R file looks like:

```
library('shiny')
library('ggplot2')

dt <-read.csv('file.csv')
ui <- fluidPage(
        plotOutput("plot1", height = 550, click = "plot1_click"),
    fluidRow(
        column(3,
        sliderInput("Obs", "Number of Books", min = 1, max = nrow(up), value = 50)
        ),
        column(3, offset = 3, 
               h4("Legends"),
         verbatimTextOutput("selected")
        )  
      )
    )
server <- function(input, output) {
   mydata <- reactive({
    dt[1:as.numeric(input$Obs),]
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    test <- mydata()
    ggplot(data = test, aes(x = test[,2], y = test[,1])) +  geom_point()
  }) 
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    file <- mydata()
    nearPoints(file, input$plot1_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = FALSE)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Shiny `nearPoints()` is working perfectly without this slider input. When I used slider input, I can't get the row data until max. Is there any approach to work with the slider input? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with renderUI?

Comment: Just to check that I understand, you want the value from `input$plot1_click` to be used in your `sliderInput`? If that's what you want, you will need to move your `sliderInput` function into a `renderUI` output function inside your `server.R`. You can then render it in `ui.R` with `uiOutput`. Here is the [relevant documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html)

Comment: slider input is "Obs", and it controls the numbers of rows to pass to the function. "input$plot1_click" is point where mouse clicked.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, data and plot?  It is very hard to answer your question without providing enough details for OPs to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. It seems `nearPoints` is not able to tell which columns of your dataset are displayed because of the `aes(x = test[,2], y = test[,1])` statement. Another possible fix sould be to set the parameters `xvar` and `yvar` in `nearPoints`.

```
library('shiny')
library('ggplot2')

dt <-mtcars
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", height = 550, click = "plot1_click"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           sliderInput("Obs", "Number of Cars", min = 1, max = nrow(dt), value = 50)
    ),
    column(3, offset = 3, 
           h4("Legends"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected")
    )  
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    dt[1:as.numeric(input$Obs),]
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    test <- mydata()
    ggplot(data = test, aes(mpg, wt)) +  geom_point()
  }) 
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    file <- mydata()
    nearPoints(file, input$plot1_click, threshold = 100, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = FALSE)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Quick note**: Please try to make the code in your question reproducible by using one of the default datasets in R. You can get a list of all available datasets by calling `data()`.